# Xampp is not working in Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, xampp

I have currently tried to install Xampp in Vista operating system. But my Appache and MySql is not working. What should i do now? Is Xampp not compatible in Vista operating system?

Comment: Do you have something more specific than not working?

Comment: I really want mean that Xampp is not running in my Vista operating system.

Comment: Do you have iis 7 installed in vista ?

Comment: yes kunal i have iis 7

Comment: Your iis 7 may be running on port 80 and apache is also configured to run on port 80 which leading into conflict and thus apache is not starting . you should assign new port to run apache server